# Accessing socket.ltn12 from openresty using opm package manager

Tags: lua, openresty, luarocks

## Context

- Openresty 6.x

`ltn12` is a module from the `luasocket` library.

This library can be installed with `luarocks` package manager.

`Openresty` is discouraging the use of [`luarocks`](https://openresty.org/en/using-luarocks.html) for [`OPM`](https://opm.openresty.org/).

But i can't find any available `luasocket` library or `ltn12` module in `OPM`.

## Question

How can i use `ltn12` module from `luasocket` library using `OPM` ?

## Edit (temporary solutions)

- The package [`duhoobo/lua-resty-smtp`](https://opm.openresty.org/package/duhoobo/lua-resty-smtp/) is available at OPM and provides `ltn12` accessible with `require resty.smtp.ltn12`
- You can copy the `lib/resty/smtp/ltn12.lua` available on the package, don't forget to change module name into the file

Answer (score 1):

Luarocks is supported by openresty. It's not bundled but you can install it for the bundled version of openresty. Follow the instructions here:

https://openresty.org/en/using-luarocks.html

and replace `/usr/local/openresty/luajit` with your own `openresty/luajit` path

```
wget http://luarocks.org/releases/luarocks-2.0.13.tar.gz
tar -xzvf luarocks-2.0.13.tar.gz
cd luarocks-2.0.13/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openresty/luajit \
    --with-lua=/usr/local/openresty/luajit/ \
    --lua-suffix=jit \
    --with-lua-include=/usr/local/openresty/luajit/include/luajit-2.1
make
sudo make install
```